# Entry request of 2 tables with best of 3

Tags: iptables

How do I make a request that will list the names and rating of the top 3 in the tables

Comment: What have you tried?  Which database are you using?  Keywords such as `top` or `limit` and `order by` and `join` will get you there.

Comment: Mathieu, welcome to StackOverflow.  It's customary to first attempt a solution and display what you've attempted so that the community can better assist as well as they can be assured they aren't doing your work for you (and being taken advantage of).  Welcome to the community and good luck in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [PostgreSQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v8MZLLnUnYbxm7geGuydd9/0):

```
SELECT name, grade 
FROM students
JOIN grades USING(student_id)
WHERE sex = 'm'
ORDER BY grade desc
LIMIT 3
```

- `JOIN` the tables
- filter by gender using `WHERE`
- sort it in descending order (by grade) using `ORDER BY..desc` so the bigger numbers are at the top
- trim the number of results to 3, using the `LIMIT`

---

### [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c47e3/7):

```
SELECT TOP 3 s.name, g.grade 
FROM students s
JOIN grades g ON ( s.student_id = g.student_id )
WHERE sex = 'm'
ORDER BY grade desc
```

- `JOIN` the tables
- filter by gender using `WHERE`
- sort it in descending order (by grade) using `ORDER BY..desc` so the bigger numbers are at the top
- trim the number of results to 3, using the `TOP` at the beginning of the query

---

Note: you may want to include a unique ID in your results, since you may have many students with the same name, making the result ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 3 G.student_id, S.name, S.sex, G.grade
FROM Grades G
INNER JOIN Student S
    ON G.student_id = S.student_id
WHERE S.sex = 'm'
ORDER BY grade DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DB is Oracle , then use :

```
select name, grade 
  from
(
select s.name, g.grade, dense_rank() over (order by grade desc) dr
  from students s join grades g on ( s.student_id = g.student_id )
 where s.sex = 'm'
)
where dr <= 3;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo(for Oracle)*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/949980/6)

If DB is Mysql or PostgreSQL, then use :

```
select s.name, g.grade
  from students s join grades g on ( s.student_id = g.student_id )
 where s.sex = 'm'
 order by g.grade desc 
 limit 3;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo(for MySQL)*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f18694/10)

[*SQL Fiddle Demo(for PostgreSQL)*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1869/2)

Answer (score 1):

you can use rownum to fetch this result.

You can try below one and tweak it , if necessary.

Select * from (SELECT st.name,gr.grade FROM students st , grades gr 
where st.student_id = gr.student_id and st.sex = 'm' order by 
grade DESC)  where 
rownum <= 3 ;

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds like come from a Student doing assignment! Anyway, some Oracle SQL as follows may be helpful.

```
SELECT STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_GRADE
FROM (
      SELECT S.NAME AS "STUDENT_NAME", G.GRADE AS "STUDENT_GRADE"
      FROM STUDENTS S JOIN GRADES G USING (STUDENT_ID)
      WHERE S.SEX='m'
      ORDER BY 2
      )
WHERE ROWNUM < 4;
```

Oracle in later versions:

```
SELECT S.NAME AS "STUDENT_NAME", G.GRADE AS "STUDENT_GRADE"
FROM STUDENTS S JOIN GRADES G USING (STUDENT_ID)
WHERE S.SEX='m'
ORDER BY 2
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```